# Navigation Properties and Lookup Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Code First entity that looks like the following:

```
public class Account
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int AccountTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountTypeId")]
    public virtual AccountType AccountType { get; set; }
}
```

`AccountType` is a lookup table which is treated as read-only. We will never want to modify it.

When I query an account, both `AccountTypeId` and `AccountType` are populated with correct values from database. However, when updating either of these properties, the other property does not get updated until we call `SaveChanges()` making a trip to the server. We didn't want to have early hits to server to save stuff, and also for some unit test of the entity we could not depend on call to `dbContext.SaveChanges()` method so we overrode the navigation property to get its value from an offline collection like this:

```
public class Account
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int AccountTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountTypeId")]
    public virtual AccountType AccountType
    {
        get
        {
            return AccountTypeCollection.GetById(this.FormatTypeId);
        }
        set
        {
            this.AccountTypeId = (value ?? AccountTypeCollection.None).Id;
        }
    }
}
```

With that we could still use the `AccountType` navigation property in LINQ queries that do joins and make sure it is always in sync with `AccountTypeId`. The problem we found, however, is that in some cases we get big performance hits. For example when we get some hundred transactions from the `Transaction` entity, which has has a relationship with `Account` and try to modify one, EF tries to save all the hundreds of Account records in the database because it thinks their `AccountType` is changed! Why does this happen? How can we prevent it?

If we unmap `AccountType` with [NotMapped] then that won't happen. But then cannot participate this property in any LINQ-to-Entity queries any more.

Is there any way we can use lookup tables from offline C# collections and still be able to use them in LINQ-to-Entities without these problems? Enum types are just too limiting and can't be extended. What's the right way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel all modified `AccountType` by overriding the [**`SaveChanges`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    // dbsets

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries<AccountType>()
            .Where(at => at.State == EntityState.Modified);
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

All modified `AccountType` in the application will not updated to the database.

Comment: Nope, it does not try to update `AccountType` entities. It thinks all `Account` entities are changed on their `AccountType` property, and tries to update all those accounts. Sorry for confusing naming.

Comment: @orad, then change the `ChangeTracker` usage to `ChangeTracker.Entries<Account>()`

Comment: Well, that would untrack all accounts, even if they are really changed. I need to find a way to avoid false updates.